# Plot function of two variables [2D plot]

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have a function `f[x_,t_]=Sin[10*x-2*t]` and I want to plot `f vs x` for different values of `t` on the same plot window.

I have tried with `Table` command but its showing in different plot windows.

Here is the code

```
f[x_, t_] = Sin[10*x - 2*t];
Table[Plot[f[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Also I would like to plot it with different colors.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `Table` inside the plot and use `Evaluate`

```
f[x_, t_] = Sin[10*x - 2*t];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[x, t], {t, 0, 10}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]